# Is That Possible multiple Radio Button select in android?

Tags: android, radio-button, radiobuttonlist

Is That possible select multiple radio button at one times? Just like checkbok.I have to show more in figure.

[image]

Comment: Any problem using checkboxes instaed?

Answer (score 10):

Radiobutton in wikipedia says

> A radio button or option button is a type of graphical user interface
>   element that allows the user to choose only **one** of a predefined set of
>   options.

You would have to just use checkboxes instead of radio button for allowing multiple options to be selected,else you are doing something which is inherently wrong in a UI be it mobile/web.

:-)

Answer (score 9):

If you don't put them all in a `RadioGroup` then yes. Either put them in several groups or manage them yourself completely.

But it's confusing for the user if you use radio buttons that behave like checkboxes.

Comment: I would say that this answer is the right one, because you can use still radio buttons with multi selection , but you have to move them outside of the RadioGroup , and maybe you have to manage them manually. If you don't want this action then just use checkbox where multi selection is allowed.